# custom UITableViewCellStyle

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I want to make custom uitableviewcellstyle to make comments in my app. I want uitableviewcell with comment text, number of likes, author's name, date etc...
Have you any ideas?
I've created method, but I don't know how realize it.
My code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)getCommentTableCellWithTableView:(UITableView *)tableView commentText:(NSString *)commentText numberOfRows:(NSInteger)numberOfRows numberOfLikes:(NSString *)numberOfLikes date:(NSString *)date writer:(NSString *) writerName {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TitleCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you add a new class that Inherit from `UITableViewCell`. Customizing table view cell works perfect!

Comment: Can you give link with tutorial to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry I can't find a tutorial with clear steps, but you can search some related posts or questions on this site.
Hope the simple code below could help you.

**Here is a doc may helps too, take your time to have a look** ;)
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

---

New class inherit from UITableViewCell,  CustomCell.h:
(Tips:`File`->`New File`->`Objective-C class`->set class name & choose the subclass `UITableViewCell`)

```
@interface MapsListViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
    // Add iVars that you want.
}
// Some custom methods
```

CustomCell.m:

```
// ...
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
// ...
// Some custom methods
- (void)setAuthorName:(NSString *)name
{
    // ...
}
```

TableViewController.m:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CategoriesListViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    CategoriesListViewCell * customCell = (CategoriesListViewCell *)cell;
    // Set your data:
    [customCell setAuthorName:@"God"];
    // ...etc.

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of us using the newer (iOS 6 and up) `UITableView` API for dequeueing cells namely`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` this is actually guaranteed to return an instantiated cell so we can't perform the nil check and manually call `initWithStyle`. Therefore the best solution is to subclass `UITableViewCell` and manually enforce the style in initialisation.

So as an example if we wanted a cell with the `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` style we would create a custom subclass:

```
@interface ABCSubtitledTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@end

@implementation ABCSubtitledTableViewCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    return [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
}

@end
```

And then in our `viewDidLoad` we would register the appropriate class

```
[tableView registerClass:[ABCSubtitledTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([ABCSubtitledTableViewCell class])];
```

Making our dequeue method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ABCSubtitledTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([ABCSubtitledTableViewCell class]) forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"World";
    return cell;
}
```